# Using jars inside SolrCloud with DIH functionality

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, dataimporthandler, solr5

I have SolrCloud setup with DIH functionality.I have written custom transformers to load data into Solr.

Can I upload this jar into ZooKeeper and use in Solr?

Comment: whats the package you have created the custom Transformer?

Comment: @Abhijit my package name is com.companyname.solr.transformer